# Can't redirect within a constructor in Symfony 4

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, router, symfony4

I'm working on a client project that wasn't conceived with services and authorizations, so the user gets logged in and creates a user session.

I have to control the access in a basic "UserboardController".

I have a constructor before any methods :

```
class UserboardController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {

        $session = new Session();

        $uSession = $session->get('user');
        if (!isset($uSession)){
             return $this->redirectToRoute('logout');
        }
    }
```

I tried many ways to redirect and always get this error :

```
Call to a member function get() on null
```

Symfony will show me two other traces inside redirectToRoute from `ControllerTrait.php` :

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route, $parameters), $status);
```

and

```
return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
```

Any idea how I could simply redirect the user to the logout route ?
This is an important step as the logout method will do other actions based on cookies before logging out and redirecting to the login form.

Logout route is defined and works if the user accesses it from the URL.

Thank you

Comment: this isn't the case for controller but for the security module itself

Comment: What are you doing in your custom logout-method that e.g. Guard cant handle for you ?
Are you sure its the redirect that throws this error and not the $session->get ?
Anyway, you could maybe try

  public function __construct(SessionInterface $session) {
        if (false === $session->has('user')){
             return $this->redirectToRoute('logout');
        }
    }

Comment: It's not the session, I can retrieve other sessions and when I comment the redirectToRoute line, no error is throwed. The logout method from LoginController works without errors if I access it via the url site.com/logout.
I understand I should not do that in the constructor but it's not my code and I would have to rewrite all the login and security process. For now redirecting seems the only option, even I don't agree with it :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to access session you should pass it as argument and get benefit of autowiring. Secondly, this shouldn't be done in a controller's constructor.

Thirdly this looks like the case for the security module of symfony. Symfony when properly configure will return use by default to `/logout` route of any route that is defined as `logout` route

So what you need to do is define in security.yaml your firewalls and define in access_control the path that should be under the firewall

Check this for more clues https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could rewrite the code and use Symfony's auth system but the platworm was given to me and I can't rewrite the full system that's based on sessions  ... I added rules as you suggested and made research to correct related glitches, but their LoginController messes up all the auth system.
Do you think of any way to simply redirect to a route or controller ? Redirections won't work in the constructor but in methods.

Comment: Use events, create event listener/subcriber pass SessionInterface in construct of service and attach to event either kernel.request or kernel.controller.  In the event if session user doesn't exist just return new RedirectResponse()